# Implications of Factory Method implementations

Tags: c#, prototype

First, this is strictly a C# question!  Please restrict your knowledge to C# for this one.

In an app I am working on, we have some classes that we provide preset 'prototypes' for.  At a very high level:

```
public class Foo
{
    #region Variables / Properties

    public bool Bar { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Fooby { get; set; }

    #endregion Variables / Properties

    #region Prototypes

    public Foo SomePrototype = new Foo
    {
        Bar = false,
        Name = "Generic False State",
        Fooby = -1
    };

    public Foo SomeOtherPrototype = new Foo
    {
        Bar = true,
        Name = "Generic True State",
        Fooby = Int32.MaxValue
    };

    #endregion Prototypes

    #region Methods

    // ...Behaviors here.

    #endregion Methods
}
```

Note the 'prototypes' section.  I've always understood that in C#, the 'correct' way to do this sort of 'prototype' is:

```
public Foo SomePrototype
{
    get 
    { 
        return new Foo
        {
            Bar = false,
            Name = "Generic False State",
            Fooby = -1
        };
    }
}
```

While I guess either 'prototype' implementation could work, **Question:** what are some of the implications of the way I'm seeing in our code base (that is, the first example?)

The obvious implication to me is that all usages of the 'prototype' would just be references to that public-facing `Foo` variable, which could provide some interesting interactions...I'm just wondering if there are more to be aware of.

Comment: `Foo f = new Foo(); f.SomePrototype = new Foo { Name = "Baz" };`

Comment: That should be made an answer.  I'm so stuck in my getter-based mindset that I didn't even see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your examples there are a few differences (seen from a technical point of view, which have nothing to do with prototyping, but everything with C#):

- Example 1: uses public writable fields with a instance created once.
- Example 2: uses public readonly properties with an instance created every call.

Well, what are the differences?

- `Foo` is not immutable. So the program can modify the prototype at multiple locations in the code. In case of example 1, that would modify the prototype (`foo.SomePrototype.Fooby = -1`) that is used by all other code, which could be undesirable.
- The public field is writable, so the program can modify the reference to a prototype (`foo.SomePrototype = new Foo {...}`) which has impact on the other code that uses that prototype. Suddenly the prototype could be replace.

**Now about prototyping:**

- If you look at the prototype pattern (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_pattern), it simply states that the prototype should be used to create a new clone of it.
- Reading that article you can see that the client is responsible for creating a clone, not the class itself. Having a prototype means that you have ONE instance and create many copies of it. Your property is creating new instances every call.
- In fact you are using the factory-method pattern. Well... okay, it is a property, but still it creates an object every time you call it.
- In my opinion I would go for the a property which returns the same reference every call. The reference is stored in a private (not public) field. This way reference can never me changed.

Example:

```
public class Foo  
{  
    #region Variables / Properties

    public bool Bar { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Fooby { get; set; }

    #endregion Variables / Properties

    #region Prototypes

    static private Foo _SomePrototype = new Foo
    {
        Bar = false,
        Name = "Generic False State",
        Fooby = -1
    };

    static private Foo _SomeOtherPrototype = new Foo
    {
        Bar = true,
        Name = "Generic True State",
        Fooby = Int32.MaxValue
    };

    static public Foo SomePrototype 
    {
        get
        {
            return _SomePrototype;
        }
    }

    static public Foo SomeOtherPrototype 
    {
        get
        {
            return _SomeOtherPrototype;
        }
    }
    #endregion
}
```

To bounce back the question: what pattern do you wanna use? The prototype pattern or the factory pattern?

Comment: I think how we're using it - the factory-method pattern - is valid.  So, time to change some region names.  Thanks for the comprehensive answer!

Answer (score 2):

These two pieces of code are not different implementations of the same thing, but serve diffrent purpouses:

- #1 gives you something like an "instance singleton" ... all `Someprototype`s derived from a single instance of `Foo` will be reference-equal. Great to preserve memory, if you never change them.
- #2 gives you an independent instance for every call. Great, if you need to modify them.

Answer (score 1):

The implication is very straightforward: the first implementation converts the would-be "prototype" to a "singleton". As you correctly noted, everything that uses such prototypes is bound to use the same instance. This is not desirable, because the instance is mutable. The two objects that you have representing the generic false and true states would be very good candidates for singletons, but you should make them immutable, or present them through a read-only interface:

```
interface IFoo {
    bool Bar { get; }
    string Name { get; }
    int Fooby { get; }
}
public class Foo : IFoo {
    ...
    public static readonly IFoo SomePrototype = new Foo
    {
        Bar = false,
        Name = "Generic False State",
        Fooby = -1
    };

    public static readonly IFoo SomeOtherPrototype = new Foo
    {
        Bar = true,
        Name = "Generic True State",
        Fooby = Int32.MaxValue
    };
    ...
}
```